# Deformation of a zero-dimensional subscheme satisfying Cayley-Bacharach property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with $\text{Pic}(X) = \mathbb{Z}$.  Let $Z \in \text{Hilb}^{d}(X)$, where $\text{Hilb}^d(X)$ denotes the Hilbert scheme of $d$ points on $X$, such that $Z$ is lci and satisfies the Cayley-Bacharach property for $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$.

> **Question.** Is it always possible to deform $Z \in \text{Hilb}^d(X)$ to a point $Z^{'}$ such that $Z^{'}$ contains $d$ *distinct* points
> and satisfies Cayley-Bacharach property for $\mathcal{O}_X(n)?$

Comment: Are you familiar with the work of Jack Huizenga and his collaborators? While much of their work focuses on $\mathbb P^2$ and various rational surfaces of Picard rank $\rho(X) > 1$, Jack has at least one paper on interpolation for fat points on surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ (I think of degree $d \ge 4$ specifically). Whether he has any theorems that actually answer your question I don't know, but the paper(s) should be instructive in any case.

Comment: I did not know about the work of Jack Huizenga, but after your suggestion, I looked at the paper. The paper basically deals with the dimension of curves passing through k-fat points. But I am not able to understand how this will answer my question. Any idea?

Comment: Nothing specific, I just know that the Cayley-Bacharach property comes up in his work at times, and that he has thought about surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ (as opposed to in the abstract) on at least this one occasion.